# Can't make thread from a function in another file

Tags: c, multithreading

I have two files. **sim.c** and **devices.c**.

Here's the **sim.c**

```
...
#include "devices.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  pthread_t *tid;

  tid = (pthread_t *) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * 3);

  // this is where I start the 3 threads located in devices.c
  if (pthread_create(&tid[0], NULL, device_one, NULL)) {
    exit(1);
  }
  if (pthread_create(&tid[1], NULL, device_two, NULL)) {
    exit(1);
  }
  if (pthread_create(&tid[2], NULL, device_three, NULL)) {
    exit(1);
  }

  // wait for 3 threads to finish
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (pthread_join(tid[i], NULL)) {
      exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's **devices.c**

```
...
#include "devices.h"

extern void *device_one(void *arg) {
  printf("device one is called\n");
  return NULL;
}

extern void *device_two(void *arg) {
  printf("device two is called\n");
  return NULL;
}

extern void *device_three(void *arg) {
  printf("device three is called\n");
  return NULL;
}
```

And here's **devices.h**

```
#ifndef DEVICES_H
#define DEVICES_H

extern void *device_one(void *arg);
extern void *device_two(void *arg);
extern void *device_three(void *arg);
```

However, when I compile, I get 3 errors under sim.c saying
*undefined reference to 'device_one'

undefined reference to 'device_two'

undefined reference to 'device_three'*

Comment: Why are you declaring functions `extern` inside your `.c` implementation file? In the header file `extern` shouldn't be necessary either. Are you linking together both resulting `.o` files correctly to make the final executable?

Comment: "when I compile..." Well, *how* are you compiling?

Comment: @TavianBarnes I compile by typing "make"

Comment: This might help you understand the use of `extern`.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410632/1787434

Comment: @Dragneel Did you write the Makefile?  What commands get run when you run `make`?

Comment: @TavianBarnes No I never wrote it. It was given to me by my professor. Also, the skeleton of my files were written by my professor too. So he's the one who declared the externs in .c and .h. How do I find out what gets executed by "makefile"?

Comment: If you are having a problem with the makefile, then you should include it in the question.  Unless you are suppressing the make output (using `@`), you normally see what compilation commands are executed.

Comment: Okay I just resolved the issue. I was using an old version of the provided makefile. It works now with the new makefile.

Answer (score 1):

The errors suggest you are not linking with the `devices` module when compiling `sim.c` (which contains `main`). You could compile as:

```
gcc sim.c devices.c -I.
```

Or you can create a makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -I.
DEPS = devices.h
OBJ = sim.o devices.o
LDLIBS = -pthread

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

sim: $(OBJ)
        $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
        rm -rf $(OBJ)
```